# Simple REGEX - How to get all lines beginning with "|" - [Pipeline] to the line above ending with [Pipeline]

Tags: regex

**Explanation**

With the help of REGEX I am trying to convert italian synonym database to the following format:

```
synonym1|synonym2|synonym3
anothersynonym1|anothersynonym2
...........
......
```

At this moment I have unconverted synonyms database in this format:

```
a|       - word
|per     -it's synonym
|verso   -another synonym of the word "a" in the second row
abate|    - second word
|priore|superiore
abbacchiare|
|avvilire|deprimere
abbacchiarsi|
|abbattersi|abbiosciarsi|accasciarsi
```

**Clarification:**
I would like to use Regular Expression to match all lines beginning with "|" (pipeline) and move them to the line above to merge with the word matching with lines ending with (Pipeline) and also moving in rows beginning with "|" (second - third - fourth lines of synonyms which may be merged together, obviously when merged lines with "ending and beginning" Pipelines one of the (Pipelines) should removed to get desired format:

Example of the converted database from unconverted database above

```
a|per|verso
abate|priore|superiore
abbachiare|avvilire|deprimere
abbachiarsi|abbattersi|abbiosciarsi|accasciarsi
```

Can anybody help me to find exact REGULAR EXPRESSION by using function FIND and REPLACE with any text editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows you can use the Extended Search Mode of [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to do this in 2 steps:

1: Replace `|\r\n|` with `|` - This will find all of the first synonyms

[image: first replace]

```
a|per
|verso
abate|priore|superiore
abbacchiare|avvilire|deprimere
abbacchiarsi|abbattersi|abbiosciarsi|accasciarsi
```

2: Replace `\r\n|` with `|` - This will find all of the subsequent synonyms

[image: second replace]

```
a|per|verso
abate|priore|superiore
abbacchiare|avvilire|deprimere
abbacchiarsi|abbattersi|abbiosciarsi|accasciarsi
```

Comment: Thank you very , very much , very descriptive even with screenshots , your solution worked perfectly exactly how you wrote !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print /^(.*)\|\s*$/?"\n$1":$_' filename

a|per|verso
abate|priore|superiore
abbacchiare|avvilire|deprimere
abbacchiarsi|abbattersi|abbiosciarsi|accasciarsi
```

Or, if you are fussy about leading and trailing newlines:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print /^(.*)\|\s*$/?$.==1?$1:"\n$1":$_;END{print"\n"}' filename
a|per|verso
abate|priore|superiore
abbacchiare|avvilire|deprimere
abbacchiarsi|abbattersi|abbiosciarsi|accasciarsi
```